# SSH Key Forwarding fails as soon as I am root

Tags: ssh, git, forwarding, ssh-keys, github

## Situation

- I add a ssh-key to the chain using `ssh-add -K the_path` as user@local
- I set up key forwarding as described here https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding
- AllowAgentForwarding is enabled (local)
- ForwardAgent is not "no" in /etc/ssh_config (remote)
- echo "$SSH_AUTH_SOCK" delivers a tmp file (local)
- when I `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.com` as other@server then it logs in
- When I run `ssh-add -L` as other@server then it adds the key.

## Problem

- When I run `ssh-add -L` on root@server then it says "Could not open a connection to your authentication agent."
- When I run `ssh -vT git@bitbucket.com` as root@server then it does not log in

I hardly don't know where to fix that or what the problem is. Can someone help?

Comment: As per [your linked document](https://help.github.com/articles/using-ssh-agent-forwarding#server-must-allow-forwarding-on-inbound-connections) does the server have `AllowAgentForwarding` enabled?

Comment: Yes, it is in the sshd_config :)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you haven't started an ssh-agent session for your root user. ssh-agent requires your user to set env variables to associate your user with the correct ssh-agent process.

e.g

SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/tmp/ssh-MTQoMbTLN3Kb/agent.30851; export SSH_AUTH_SOCK;
SSH_AGENT_PID=30852; export SSH_AGENT_PID;
echo Agent pid 30852;

You may also want to look into SSHKeychain to make managing your agent and keys easier and automatic.

Comment: ForwardAgent is not enough for that? :/
Would it be a security issue on the server to have that running?

I know it's needed but currently I want to "disable" root user and use another one.

Answer (score 1):

Using `visudo` and extending the env_keep with SSH_AUTH_SOCK will solve the problem

```
Defaults    env_keep+=SSH_AUTH_SOCK
```